# Как исправить ошибку при выводе когда V[i] == a[i] весь код стопится

Tags: c++, строки, вектор, множества

```
vector<int> Vectorina(string a, string U)
{
    vector<int> V(U.size());
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < a.size())
    {
        if (V[i] == a[i])
        {
            V[j] = 1; i++; j++;
        }
        else j++;
    }
    return V;
}
```

Comment: а что ваш код делает?

Comment: @timur, ставит 1 в ячейках где буквы в двух словах совпадают

Comment: Ну тогда сравнивайте **эти** буквы `if (U[i] == a[i])`. Цикл надо ещё внимательнее `while (i < a.size() && i < U.size())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял из комментариев задача такая:

есть 2 строки, надо выполнить построчное сравнение и записать в массив 1 для каждого совпадения букв

массив должен быть размером со вторую строку, после сравнения он должен содержать первые N элементов равных 1 и все остальные равные 0.

Если я понял правильно, тогда код должен выглядеть так (я чуть переназвал переменные для лучшего понимания):

```
vector<int> Vectorina(const string& str1, const string& str2)
{
    // создаём результирующий массив размером со строку str2 и заполненный нулями
    vector<int> res(str2.size(), 0);

    // определяем сколько букв в строках требуется просмотреть,
    // при этом выбирается минимальные из размеров строк, чтобы не выходить за пределы строк в случае, если одна строка больше по размеру, чем другая
    const size = min(str1.size(), str2.size());

    int pos = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        // если буквы в одинаковых позициях в строках совпадают - 
        // добавляем еще один элемент в результирующий массив равные 1
        if (str1[index] == str2[index])
        {
            res[pos++] = 1;
        }
    }

    // вернуть результат
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В ответах, простите уж, очередное "зачем просто, если можно сложно"...

```
vector<int> Vectorina(const string& a, const string& U)
{
    vector<int> V;
    for(auto i1 = a.begin(), i2 = U.begin(); i1 != a.end() && i2 != U.end();
        V.push_back(*i1++ == *i2++));
    return V;
}
```

Comment: У тебя выходит из цикла когда появляется 2 единица у меня в коде

Comment: Не очень понял, что и где появляется. Для каких строк получается неверный вывод?

Comment: Например, что здесь - https://ideone.com/7JArvd - не так? Может, вы его неверно используете как-то? :)

Answer (score 0):

У вас несколько ошибок

1. вы можете выйти за границы массива `U` - нигде нет проверки на это ограничение
2. вы сравниваете значение элемента массива V, хотя он заполнен, что там внутри содержится не понятно и в Release это должно просто рухнуть
3. ваш цикл `while` может быть бесконечным
4. лучше передавать значения строк в функцию по ссылкам и сделать их константами

   ```
    vector<int> Vectorina(const string& a, const string& U)
   ```

Вместо

```
if (V[i] == a[i])
```

скорее всего имелось в виду

```
if (U[i] == a[i])
```

И тогда ваш код по идее должен выглядеть так:

```
vector<int> Vectorina(string a, string U)
{
    vector<int> V(min(a.size(), U.size()), 0);
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < min(a.size(), U.size())
    {
        if (U[i] == a[i])
        {
            V[j] = 1; 
            i++; 
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
    return V;
}
```

Comment: мне кажется в `else` место `j++` надо писать `i++`

Comment: if (U[i] != a[i])  вечный цикл

Comment: @Danis, @AR Hovsepyan, да, скорее всего имелось в виду `if (U[j] == a[i])`

Comment: @Boris0 чтобы не уйти за размер массива `V`, хотя согласен  - надо было написать `while ((i < a.size() && j < U.size())`, но лучше бы вам вначале было бы все таки пояснить, а что конкретно вы хотите получить на выходе, т.е. что должна сделать функция

Comment: Почему если менять где стоит else {j++} на else {i++} выводится строка 0-ей, а если оставить то ничего не выводится

Comment: @Boris, потому что если `{j++}`, то этот `j` нигде в `while` не применяется при условии, что `V[0] != a[0]` и получается бесконечный цикл, поскольку `i` не меняется (ведь изменение только внутри условия, которое не выполняется), а выход из цикла у вас завязано именно на `i`

Comment: Я переписал код, но там где у меня должны быть дальше 1-цы стоят 0-ли
vector<int> Vectorina(string a, string U)
{
 vector<int> V(U.size());
 int i = 0, j = 0;
 while (i < a.size())
 {
  if (U[i] == a[i])
  {
   V[j] = 1;
   i++;
   j++;
  }
  else
  {
   i++;
  }
 }
 return V;
}

Comment: @Boris, сейчас у вас `i++` происходит на каждом шагу, поэтому можно ваш код упростить до `for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {if (U[i] == a[i]) V[j++] = 1;}`. Т.е. правильно ли я понимаю, что ваш код делает следующее - сравнивает две строки побуквенно и если буквы совпадают он записывает в `V` единицу, таким образом если `a` и `U` равны `xabcd`,`yabcz` соответственно, то в массиве `V` будет записано `{1, 1, 1, 0, 0}`? Вам именно этого надо?

Comment: Да типо того, сверху написали код, но он не работает дальше у меня когда ставится 2-ая 1-ца,

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113697/discussion-between-boris-and-zhihar).